# Eclipse: slow refresh after svn update

Tags: eclipse, refresh

After updating my project, Eclipse (Indigo on Windows) hangs for a couple of minutes refreshing the project. Even if only just one small folder or only 1 file is updated, it seems to refresh the entire project.

My project has 10.000+ files in it, so I can see why refreshing everything can take a while, but why is the *entire* project being refreshed?

The workspace and working copy are on my local computer. The SVN server is in a LAN.
I disabled automatic build and refresh in the Eclipse settings.

Any ideas why a simple refresh is taking so long ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happening when timestamps of files that don't need updating don't agree with the timestamps stored by the version control system.  Try removing the local copy and checking out a fresh version.